# php artisan migrate not working Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Everything was fine until I changed my computer. I'm trying to migrate my database with `php artisan migrate` but I get this error

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = grain and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712
    708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
    713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    714▕             );
    715▕         }
    716▕     }

      +33 vendor frames 
  34  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Any attempt to interact with the database gives me the same error

this is my .env configuration

```
    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=grain
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Do you have `mysql` set up on this new computer? I.e. can you do `mysql -u root` in your Terminal/Command Line? Have you run all the appropriate steps, like `composer install`, etc.? This seems like an issue with your new computer not being configured properly, so you'll have to do some digging to find the exact cause.

Comment: Regarding "Any attempt to interact with the database gives me the same error": check the connection to your DB via the terminal.

Please specify how your database works. Are you using a docker container, a local installation, or something else?

Comment: Also, remember that before you can perform the migrations themselves, you must have the DB schema itself created.

Comment: @slaff.bg yeah but that will trigger another error "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database"

Comment: @TimLewis You are right, the problem actually came from the fact that I changed pc. On the old I was using MAMP and the new XAMPP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because on my old pc I was using MAMP and now I'm using XAMPP so in the `database.php` file the `unix_socket` path was wrong.

So go to your `my.cnf` file and search the socket path then make sur that the socket path is the same as the `unix_socket` path in your `database.php` file